# Combination of VLOOKUP and IMPORTRANGE in an array formula doesn't work

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup, importrange

I would like to import some data with the combination of ARRAYFORMULA, VLOOKUP, and IMPORTRANGE like this:

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(A3:A,importrange(T3:T,"sheet1!A:AA"),21,false))
```

in column T, there are individual sheet URLs.

However, this doesn't work because the formula only uses sheet URL in T3 than in another row other than row 3, it says `#N/A` because the value in A4 doesn't appear on a sheet URL in T3, where sheet URL must be the one in T4.

How to correct the formula above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IMPORTRANGE` does not support array range reference input.

the workaround would be to use multiple `IMPORTRANGEs` in an array like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, {IMPORTRANGE(T2, "sheet1!A:AA");
                                     IMPORTRANGE(T3, "sheet1!A:AA");
                                     IMPORTRANGE(T4, "sheet1!A:AA")}, 21, 0), ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! Actually, there are URL links to another spread sheets, which are all different, in cells T3:T. In my formula above, importrange works only T3, and it doesn't work below T4...that is the problem which I would like to solve.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have a copy of my sheets below.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r9_nmm8z5qzeMl3Fptr4RD9kS4uzLBQU9Qp0w8Y-T5g/edit#gid=0

in Column U2-U4, I only use `vlookup` and `importrange` which works as I intend. In Column V2, I use the 'arrayformula' which doesn't work as I want, and I would like to get the same result by using `arrayformula` in Column V2-V4 as in Column U2-U4.

Comment: @HisakiTokushima check your sheet - thats the only way how to use ARRAYFORMULA with combination of IMPORTRANGE. (answer updated)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I understand that it's difficult to use ARRAYFORMULA in this case. Actually, there are more than 2000 rows so it might be difficult to use the alternative way that you suggest but I'll think about what I should.